# Can a slave interface have an IP address?

Tags: networking, network-bridge

I created a bridge and assigned a physical interface to it as a slave. Now both have the same MAC and IP addresses. I thought only the master would have an IP address. Is something wrong ?

---

2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000

```
link/ether 80:ee:73:f2:0b:e9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

inet 10.11.234.47/24 brd 10.11.234.255 scope global dynamic enp1s0

   valid_lft 35612sec preferred_lft 35612sec
```

...
67: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000

```
link/ether 80:ee:73:f2:0b:e9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

inet 10.11.234.47/24 brd 10.11.234.255 scope global dynamic br0

   valid_lft 28166sec preferred_lft 28166sec

inet6 fe80::82ee:73ff:fef2:be9/64 scope link 

   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong. The slave cannot have MAC and IP addresses *of its own* because it inherits the master's MAC and IP addresses.